# Windows Server: not enough space on disk (yet still plenty of free space even in the error message itself)

Tags: windows, disk-space-utilization, storage-spaces

I've got a fileserver running Windows Server and I'm using the storage pool technology to create volumes where I store the files.

I tried to move some files from one of the volumes to another but I got this weird message saying that there is no free space to copy a 37MB files but showing that there's still 1,60TB of free space

[image].

On Linux in a similar situation I would check for some inodes issues, but I can't find a proper reason why the copy should fail here. Please note that I've even checked for permissions error (not an issue here) and tried to copy with robocopy (error 112 for lack of free space on destination).

There's no quota policy applied to that volumes or to new directories and the volumes are NTFS.

Any hints or suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: Q1: How many files are you trying to copy? Q2: What’s your cluster size on the destination disk? See… With a huge amount of files and some big cluster size you can run out of the disk space pretty fast.

Comment: That might be the problem (the cluster size thing): is there an easy way to check the "free clusters" on the destination volume?

Comment: Not really. That's also hard to calculate since the system can't anticipate how many clusters files will occupie that will be added in the future. You can [check your cluster size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81236/how-can-i-view-the-allocation-unit-size-of-a-ntfs-partition-in-vista) and use it for an estimate ... with a cluster size of 64kb thousands of 1kb files will obviously use up one cluster each, a 70kb file will use up two clusters etc. The larger the file the less it matters. But with your disk size it is most probably 4kb.

Comment: A couple of thoughts: sparse files may affect this. Also partitions with a 64k cluster size cannot use compression, so any compressed files would need to be uncompressed. Some large files of types that compress well could be 10x larger.

Comment: And files 1kb or less may be stored in the MFT and calculation may be distorted. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45645080/175990

Answer (score 1):

It's not only about free space AS IS, it's about a) Number of the free clusters, and b) Cluster size. Say, if you have big cluster size (talking megabytes here) and lots of small, but not not VERY small, because these are written inside MFT within NTFS file systems, say metadata + data within the same place, files... You can run out of space pretty quickly! This is where FSUtil from Windows might come up handy.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil

What you need to do is to a) Open PowerShell cmd, and b) Run "fsutil" with "fsinfo" and "ntfsinfo" parameters followed by your destination drive letter or path if there's no drive letter assigned for whatever reason.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-fsinfo

Something like this:

`fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo YourDestinationCopyDriveLetter:`

Within the output you check for "Free Clusters" and "Bytes per Cluster" reported values. If you multiply them you'll get your approximate maximum number of not very small (small files are stored within MFT and an actual clusters never touched, like I ment'd before) files drive can accept.

Hope this helped :)